# Why serving static file with django or other web framework is discouraged in production?

Tags: performance, nginx, io, webserver

It is a common practice to serve static files with NGINX, not with your Python (or PHP) based web application, for performance reason.

Some people argue that NGINX is written in C and your web app is written in a dynamic language, which is slower. But I think for IO-oriented tasks C does not out-perform Python or PHP significantly.

Why serving static file with django or other web framework has lower performace?

Comment: Does your app have all the nginx's tcp_nodelay/sendfile/aio/etc. options? They greatly speed up serving static files and also reduce cpu and memory usage. You're app probably does something simple and inefficient like reading file and sending response.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @Anatoly Not really.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Nginx is reverse proxy. Backend goes through proxy, static files served straight from file system bypass any backend processing.

Why not to serve static through backend? This question is obvious, performance and free up heavy backend processes. Nginx easily serves thousand of connections asynchronous (20-50mb) comparison to even multithreaded hundreds backend processes which make sense to use for dynamic requests primarily.

Disk system I/O is cheap, backend is expensive.